# linking an image on page from an array in php

Tags: php

Why isnt this working?

```
 <?php
            $computers = array();

                $computers[101] = array(
                "name" => "phantom NXZT",
                "img" => "img/phantom.jpg",
                "cpu" => "Intel i7 4770K Quadcore",
                "gpu" => "GTX 780 3GB GDDR5",
                "ram" => "16GB Corsair 1800mhz",
                "hdd" => "Seagate 2TB Hard Drive",
                "ssd" => "SanDisk 120GB Solid State",
                "price" => 1200
                );

            ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $computers["img"];?>">
```

Its coming up as a broken img link, i want it to display the image url into the image src. I dont understand why it is not working please help?

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $computers[101]["img"];?>">

Comment: Put that as an answer.

Comment: @KA_lin - good one, plus double-quotes should be replaced by single quotes around `img`... also, defining `$computers` as an array before is totally useless...

Comment: Side note: Make it valid, add the `alt`-attribute. ;)

Comment: [OT] Am I the only one appreciating the sheer irony of this?

Answer (score 1):

Because of [101] :)

```
            <img src="<?php echo $computers[101]['img'];?>">
```

Mmm sorry, KA_lin answered in first

Comment: think you'll need to replace the double-quotes around `img` with single quotes...?

Comment: @MrMojoRisin: no sweat

Comment: @KA_lin However, I have not copy your answer ;)

Comment: @MrMojoRisin: Put single quotes so I can believe you :))